# View apps by release date in app store

Tags: app-store

There used to be a way in appstore to sort apps by release date. But now in iOS 9 and 10, I am not able to find this. Has this been removed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this in the iOS app itself - Apple appears to have removed that kind of sorting capability some time ago (along with Sort by Rating)

This site, however, might be of some use...
http://www.148apps.com/newest-148-app-store-additions/1/any/